# How to modify the size of a global array inside a constructor

Tags: java, arrays, size, global-variables

I need double the number of slots in the array if the slots are full. My code currently sits at 
My hierarchy is

```
public class Stack {
   Object filearray[]= new Object [5];

   public Object push(element) {
       if (filearray[filearray.length - 1] != null) {
            Object temp_array[] = new Object[filearray.length*2];
            int origonal = filearray.length*2;
            //adding the element that the user passed in
            temp_array[0] = element;
            for(int i =0; i<filearray.length;i++) {
                temp_array[i+1] =filearray[i];
            }
            //wiping the filearray clear
            Object filearray[] = new Object [origonal];
            for (int i=0; i<temp_array.length; i ++) {
                filearray [i]=temp_array[i];
            }
            return filearray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you must you array of objects ? what about a vector/list ? And what exactly is the problem you are having ?

Comment: @giorashc, it unfortunately has to be an array as per the instructions.

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: This is a terrible question.  So full of self contradictions that it is almost impossible to know what you are REALLY asking.  1) There is no constructor here.  2) there are no global variables here.  3) You don't say what `push` is actually supposed to do.  4) You don't explain what your problem / state an actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new double sized array is never kept in the instance so look at the following to fix it :

```
public Object push(element)
{

    if (filearray[filearray.length - 1] != null)
    {
        Object temp_array[] = new Object[filearray.length*2];
        int origonal = filearray.length*2;
        //adding the element that the user passed in
        temp_array[0] = element;
        for(int i =0; i<filearray.length;i++)
        {
            temp_array[i+1] =filearray[i];
        }

        this.filearray = temp_array;
    }
}
```

You do not need to wipe the old array just change it reference to the new allocated array.

Answer (score 2):

In the above, you're creating a new *local* array, scoped to the method. You're not changing the original class member. This:

```
    //wiping the filearray clear
    Object filearray[] = new Object [origonal];
```

creates an array `filearray` that hides the class member. You simply need to create your temporary array and then do:

```
    filearray = temp_array;
```

to swap the references.

I would perhaps investigate [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), since it'll do all of this under the covers, and (unrelated) Java [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), since that'll give you type safety (unless you *really* want to store `Objects`)

Comment: @giorashc is correct, I tried to copy the array into a bigger array. How would I switch the references over since I have my global variable defined? I apologize for the possible haze of the question

Comment: Agreed. Amended/expanded/rewritten etc.!